Yet another identity for central binomial coefficients?
Let $n$ be a positive integer. We know that $n=2k+r$ for a non-negative integer $k$ and for some $r \in \{0,1\}$.
I've arrived at the following conjecture:
$$\sum_{j=0}^{k} \binom{n}{2j}\binom{2j}{j} 2^{n-2j} = \binom{2n}{n}.$$
Do you know if this equality holds in general? If so, would you be so kind as to recommend a source where I can consult a proof of it?
Thank you very much for your attention.

I have just edited the question. Sorry!

See this and this, found with Approach Zero.
